# Delphi doubles single quotes while searching with FindFirst/FindeNext

Tags: delphi, path, find

I'm using Delphi 2010 on Windows 7 and have a problem with single quotes doubling while searching a directory recursively.

This is my code that searches for directories.

```
  if FindFirst(aPath + '*', faDirectory, sr) = 0 then
    try
      repeat
        if  (sr.Name <> '.') and (sr.Name <> '..') then
          if (sr.Attr and faDirectory) = faDirectory then
            SearchFolderEx(aPath + sr.Name + '\', aSearchMasks);

      until FindNext(sr) <> 0;
    finally
      FindClose(sr);
    end;
```

Now with a path like this (starting at "C:\New folder\")

```
C:\New folder\New Folder's\New Text Document.txt
```

FindFirst/FindeNext doubles the single quote

```
'New Folder''s'
```

and FindData.cFileName from the TSearchRec looks like this

```
('N', 'e', 'w', ' ', 'F', 'o', 'l', 'd', 'e', 'r', '''', 's', #0, #0, ...)
```

where could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: The only problem that needs to be fixed is your `folder's` name (pun intended).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no problem here and nothing needs to be fixed. The `'` is the string delimiter and is simply escaped for representation as `''`. When the debugger shows you `''` in a string, that's just its way of representing a single quote character.

The documentation covers this topic here: [Character Strings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Fundamental_Syntactic_Elements#Character_Strings).

So,

```
''''
```

is a string of length 1 whose single element is the quote symbol.

Likewise

```
'New Folder''s'
```

is a Delphi string literal defining the string

```
New Folder's
```

The debugger shows you the contents of the variable using the same rules as are used for string literals.

Comment: +1. IOW, it's just a display issue when examining variables in the debugger, and has no impact on the actual code's behavior or results.

Comment: It should be interesting to note that the behavior is version dependent. D2007 debugger displays a single `'` character as `'''`, while on XE it is `''''` (apparently D2010 also) (ansi-wide doesn't matter).